# Creating Clojure vector(s) using values pulled from map(s) via keywords

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure, key-value

I have a Clojure vector of maps used as a lookup table:

```
(def data 
  [{map1},{map2},...,{nth-map}])
```

Each map in the vector contains two key/value pairs:

```
{:key1 "Value1", :key2 "Value2"}
```

So the entire structure looks like this:

```
(def data
  [{:key1 "Value1-1", :key2 "Value2-1"}, ; map1
   {:key1 "Value1-2", :key2 "Value2-2"}, ; map2
                     |
                     |
                     V
   {:key1 "Value1-n", :key2 "Value2-n"}]) ; nth-map
```

I'd like to migrate this into a database table. I already have a function that inserts values into a table row. It takes a single vector with each item in the vector representing a column in the row:

```
(defn insert-row [column1-value column2-value]
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (sql/insert-values
      :table                           ; table name
      [:column1 :column2]              ; table column names
      [column1-value column2-value]))) ; values to be inserted into row
```

What I need is a function that goes through the entire vector of maps and for each map it creates a vector of just that map's values:

```
[Value1 Value2]
```

I think I can use my existing database function `insert-row` as a parameter to `map`:

```
(map insert-row values-from-map)
```

where `values-from-map` represents an outer vector containing inner vectors (each containing its respective values) for each map in the original vector:

```
[[Value1-1 Value2-1]
 [Value1-2 Value2-2]
 [Value1-n Value2-n]]
```

This would take each vector created and pass it to the `insert-values` function.

I can create a single vector containing all the values from one keyword:

```
user=> (vec (map :key1 data))      
["Value1" "Value2" ... "nth=Value"]
```

How would I create an outer vector containing all the inner vectors?

```
[[Value1-1 Value2-1][Value1-2 Value2-2]...[Value1-n Value2-n]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you still defined your vector of maps as "data":

```
(into [] (map #(into [] (vals %)) data))
```

Comment: If you really need a vector of vectors, then use `(into [] (map #(into [] (vals %)) data))`. I think you'd be fine with just `(map vals data)`, though.

Comment: `(map vals data)` is exactly what I needed. Also, it's as embarrassingly simple as I suspected it would be. Thanks very much, WolfeFan. I'm still trying to wrap my head around functional programming.

Comment: why not use `mapv` instead of `(into [] (map ...`?

Answer (score 6):

```
user=> (vec (for [m data] ((juxt :key1 :key2) m)))
[["Value1-1" "Value2-1"] ["Value1-2" "Value2-2"]]
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. `vals` makes no guarantee about the order of the keys, but your code guarantees that they get put in proper order.

Comment: `(map vals data)` appears to populate my database with the rows in expected order. In my case it doesn't really matter. But I like the fact that this version is more robust in that regard. Thanks, Michiel.